# Why is this a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[Heathrow T3 to Euston Station](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108518/heathrow-t3-to-euston-station) has been marked as a duplicate of [What it the fastest way, for four people plus luggage, to Heathrow T2 from King's Cross Station?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49450/what-it-the-fastest-way-for-four-people-plus-luggage-to-heathrow-t2-from-king) . Could somebody explain why? Euston and King's Cross, while not a million miles away, are certainly not close enough that I'd be happy to assume the same route would get one to both fastest. Indeed, the Euston question has the potential for some answers with caveats that simply wouldn't exist in the King's Cross question (something along the lines of "if you're happy to walk a short distance above ground with your luggage you should go to Euston Square, else you might consider catching the Southbound Bakerloo at Paddington and changing onto the Victoria at Oxford Circus" (don't take that second route as gospel, this is just an example)).

While I admit the answers given aren't of the highest quality, there's no reason there couldn't be a better answer, which provides necessary detail that simply does not apply to the King's Cross question.

Is there some policy on "fastest way from X to Y" questions that means this has to be closed, or do five people just not realise that King's Cross and Euston aren't the same place?

Comment: For what it's worth, either the closevotes have expired  or the question was re-opened after closure, so the question is moot.

Answer (score 2):

The question was reopened by popular demand. So I guess we can say it wasn't a duplicate after all.